# How to get default Task Status and all Closed Status values of Task Object

Tags: apex

I have a requirement where I have to get Default `Task` Status and Closed Status.

```
     String defaultTaskStatus; // variable which contains Default Status
     Set<String> taskClosedStatusSet; // Set of Closed Status
```

I checked In Task object there is no field call `isDefault` or `isClosed`.

However, there is a Standard Object called `TaskStatus`, which contains above 2 variable.

So, how we will get all required data by using 2 standard objects `Task` and `TaskStatus` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
String defaultTaskStatus = (String)[select MasterLabel from TaskStatus WHERE
                                   IsDefault=TRUE][0].get('MasterLabel');

Set<String> taskClosedStatusSet = new Set<String>();

for(TaskStatus ts: [select MasterLabel from TaskStatus WHERE IsClosed=TRUE]){
    taskClosedStatusSet.add(ts.MasterLabel);
}
```

Comment: That's correct if you are going to show the value, but if you want to compare that value to Task.Status, you should be using TaskStatus.ApiName, not TaskStatus.MasterLabel, since it's possible for them to be different, and TaskStatus.ApiName is the value that is used for Task.Status.